# Eigen version static assertion fail in binary version

Tags: drake

I installed drake binary in my ubuntu 16.04 xenial by

`curl -o drake.tar.gz https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/drake/continuous/drake-latest-xenial.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvzf drake.tar.gz -C /opt`

And I find_package(drake) in my cmake and try to do optimization.
But I got the following error

`/opt/drake/include/drake/common/autodiff.h:15:1: error: static assertion failed: Drake requires Eigen >= v3.3.3.
 static_assert(EIGEN_VERSION_AT_LEAST(3, 3, 3)`

and
`/opt/drake/include/drake/common/autodiffxd.h:232:69: error: ‘MakeAutoDiffScalar’ was not declared in this scope
    return MakeAutoDiffScalar(m_value * other, m_derivatives * other);`

I think I am including right Eigen which is located in 
`/opt/drake/include/eigen3`.

How could I fix it?
By the way in the Mac, it works well with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you've (either directly or indirectly) called `find_package(Eigen)` before you did so on Drake, in which case CMake may be finding your system Eigen rather than the Drake-provided version; this is noted here (sorry that it's not yet in a more obvious location):

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-shambhala/tree/b3d7804/drake_cmake_installed/src/pcl#eigen

If you do `find_package(drake)` first, then it should allow `find_package(Eigen)` to work later on.

If that doesn't work, could you post a link to your code in a GitHub repository, or can you make a minimal reproduction issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was when I ```target_link_libraries``` another library using different version of Eigen came in front of ```drake::drake```